# How would I go about extending the bookmarks bar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to add a "widget" to the bookmarks bar in chrome via an extension. The widget would stay fixed to the right of the bookmarks bar and have a couple of buttons that trigger different actions.

I'm quite new to chrome development so if someone could point me in the right direction for what I'm trying to do, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. Do you want to programatically add bookmarks? See [`chrome.bookmarks`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure that you are not mixing up apples and oranges, I want to point out that normally buttons for Chrome extensions do not reside in the bookmarks bar, and as others have pointed out, it may not even be possible. If you saw an extension button on Chrome, it most likely was not in the bookmarks bar OR you were actually seeing a bookmarklet.

Buttons for extensions normally appear elsewhere on the UI above the bookmarks bar. If you simply want to make an extension that manipulates bookmarks, perhaps it is fine for the button to be in the normal place.

Depending on the design, extensions don't have to have any buttons at all.

That said, if it is true that a button can not be inserted through "normal" means into the bookmark bar, but I was desperate for my extension to have one there, I might try the following: Use the [bookmark API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html) to insert a bookmarklet into the bookmark bar. That bookmarklet could then interact with any web page that was open when it was clicked. Then my extension could watch every web page open for an event that would be triggered by the bookmarklet. When the event was detected, my extension code could then take the actions I want it to take. That is kind of messy though, and not very desirable.

Depending on your needs, creating a self contained bookmarklet would be far better. You could then distribute the extension as both a self contained bookmarklet and as an extension that does little more than add the bookmarklet to the bookmarks toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add bookmarks, not widgets, to the bookmark bar.  However, you could probably add a bookmarklet (i.e., a bookmark whose URL begins with `javascript:` and runs a script on the current page when clicked) using the Chrome [Bookmark API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html).  Separate functuonality will require separate bookmarlets, though, or a single bookmarklet could add a menu to the page.

Perhaps, though, you want is a [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html) button to the right of the address bar.  Each extension can only add one button, but the button can produce a popup page with further options.